# Change Text in StaticDateTimePicker MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

i want to change the title text of the component StaticDateTimePicker
[what to replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfETd.png)

in the DOM he is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUH5S.png)

following the API documentation, I realized that I need to refer to components: Toolbar and use custom,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r7yi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QSwb.png)

I found the default toolbar, (import {DateTimePickerToolbar} from "@mui/x-date-pickers";)
but I don't know how to change this component in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Localization in Material UI to replace the text: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/localization/

The key to replace is called as `dateTimePickerToolbarTitle` (Reference: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/e4a23755d6f0516ab1ca1a7237e51db9d765343e/packages/x-date-pickers/src/locales/enUS.ts#L31)

To override your specific case:

```
<StaticDateTimePicker localeText={{ dateTimePickerToolbarTitle: 'Your Text Here' }} />
```

Comment: no it's language change, english, german...

Comment: Try `<StaticDateTimePicker localeText={{ dateTimePickerToolbarTitle: 'Your Text Here' }} />`?

Comment: thank you very much, it turned out, it remains to understand how to make friends with TS